# Textarea won't save to database using jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to dynamically add form fields using jQuery and save the input in my database. All of the fields are saving to the database just fine except for the textarea. I'm not sure what the issue is.

**View**

```
@model DailyTaskList.Models.DTL_Tasks

@{
var db = new DailyTaskList.Models.DailyTaskListEntities();
var options = db.DTL_UserOptions.Where(u => u.UserProfile.UserId == WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
var priority = db.DTL_Tasks.Select(p => p.Priority).FirstOrDefault();
var customerNames = db.DTL_Customers.Select(c => c.CustomerName);
var userSelectedTasks = options.Select(o => o.DTL_TaskTypes);


SelectList userSelectedTasksList = new SelectList(userSelectedTasks);
var priorityListItems = new SelectListItem[] {
    new SelectListItem(){ Text="", Value="0" },
    new SelectListItem(){ Text="Low", Value="1" },
    new SelectListItem(){ Text="Medium", Value="2" },
    new SelectListItem(){ Text="High", Value="3" },
    new SelectListItem(){ Text="Highest", Value="4" }
};

using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "NewTask", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "new-task-form" })) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    // Original form fields
    <div class="new-task-form-wrapper">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Customer:</label>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerId, new SelectList(db.DTL_Customers, "CustomerId", "CustomerName"), new { @class = "form-control", id = "Customer_0" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <label>Activity:</label>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TaskTypeId, new SelectList(userSelectedTasks, "TaskTypeId", "TaskName"), new { @class = "form-control", id = "Activity_0" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <label>Priority:</label>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Priority, priorityListItems, new { @class = "form-control", id = "Priority_0" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Title:</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TaskTitle, new { @class = "form-control", id = "Title_0" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group description">
            <label>Description:</label>
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.TaskDescription, new { @class = "form-control", id = "Description_0" })
        </div>
    </div>

    // Additional form fields
    <div id="additional-form-fields_0" class="hide new-task-form-wrapper">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Customer:</label>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerId, new SelectList(db.DTL_Customers, "CustomerId", "CustomerName"), new { @class = "form-control", id = "Customer_1" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <label>Activity:</label>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TaskTypeId, new SelectList(userSelectedTasks, "TaskTypeId", "TaskName"), new { @class = "form-control", id = "Activity_1" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <label>Priority:</label>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Priority, priorityListItems, new { @class = "form-control", id = "Priority_1" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Title:</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TaskTitle, new { @class = "form-control", id = "Title_1" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group description">
            <label>Description:</label>
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.TaskDescription, new { @class = "form-control", id = "Description_1" })
        </div>
    </div>

    // Form controls
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Create">Submit</button>
        <div class="btn btn-default" id="addnew">+</div>
        @*<div class="btn btn-default" id="remove">-</div>*@
    </div>
  }
}
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    CKEDITOR.replace('Description_0');

    var counter = 0;
    var additionalFormFields = $("#additional-form-fields_" + String(counter));
    var customerInput = $("#Customer_1"),
        activityInput = $("#Activity_1"),
        priorityInput = $("#Priority_1"),
        titleInput = $("#Title_1"),
        descriptionInput = $("#Description_1");

    $('#addnew').click(function () {

        if (counter == 0) {
            additionalFormFields.removeClass("hide");
        }
        else {
            var newFormFields = additionalFormFields.clone();
            additionalFormFields.after(newFormFields);
        }
        additionalFormFields.attr("id", "additional-form-fields_" + String(counter));

        customerInput.attr("id", "Customer_" + String(counter + 1));
        customerInput.attr("name", "CustomerId_" + String(counter));

        activityInput.attr("id", "Activity_" + String(counter + 1));
        activityInput.attr("name", "TaskTypeId_" + String(counter));

        priorityInput.attr("id", "Priority_" + String(counter + 1));
        priorityInput.attr("name", "Priority_" + String(counter));

        titleInput.attr("id", "Title_" + String(counter + 1));
        titleInput.attr("name", "TaskTitle_" + String(counter));

        descriptionInput.attr("id", "Description_" + String(counter + 1));
        descriptionInput.attr("name", "DescriptionId_" + String(counter));

        counter++;
        return false;
    });

    $('#new-task-form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var data = [];

        $.each($(".new-task-form-wrapper"), function (i, o) {
            data.push({
                CustomerId: $(this).find("select[name^='CustomerId']").val(),
                TaskTypeId: $(this).find("select[name^='TaskTypeId']").val(),
                Priority: $(this).find("select[name^='Priority']").val(),
                TaskTitle: $(this).find("input[name^='TaskTitle']").val(),
                TaskDescription: $(this).find("textarea[name^='DescriptionId']").val()
            });
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: 'NewTask/Index',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(data)
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: you are selecting on the name but I don't see you setting the name for that field.  if you look at the source is there a name on the text area?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your text area's name is `TaskDescription` so the more appropriate selector would be:

```
TaskDescription: $(this).find("textarea[name^='TaskDescription']").val()
```